# Is there a subversion plugin available for LibreOffice/OpenOffice similar to MagnetSVN?

Tags: svn, openoffice, libreoffice, openoffice-writer

I recently came across the plugin, MagnetSVN, for MS Office which allows for svn interaction directly from MS Word. I'm looking for something similar for LibreOffice and/or OpenOffice.

I came across OOoSVN but it wasn't exactly the same as MagnetSVN.

Comment: Re-asking *not answered* question **does not increase chances** to get answer

Comment: This is one of those questions that spans stackoverflow & superuser, at least to me. So I thought it might get additional eyeballs on it by re-posting. Sorry if I violated some ethos.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this [link](http://www.ensode.net/roller/dheffelfinger/entry/openoffice_documents_version_control_with) which discusses various approaches. One in particular seemed promising, using the `.fodt` file format with `mercurial`. This [article](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HandlingOpenDocumentFiles) in the `mercurial` wiki also provided a method using the tools `odt2txt` and `oodiff`. It isn't ideal but it's at least provides a starting point.

Additionally this IBM developerworks article, [Thinking XML: The open office file format](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-think15/) is a good primer in what's inside a LibreOffice file.

Answer (score 1):

Cite from [The Document Foundation Wiki](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Libreoffice_and_subversion) in order to completely close problem

> By defaut the documents created with libreoffice are compressed,
>   though, which is good since it keeps them at a reasonable size on the
>   local hard disk. Actually the compression is a nice feature since if
>   you change the ending of an  an open document file to .jar you get an
>   archieve containing all images and other objects included in the file
>   in their original format.
>
> The drawback is that if you change just one word in a document chances
>   are high that the compressed version of the document changes
>   completely - which leaves the version control system with a huge
>   amount of data.
>
> But don't despair:
>
> Libreoffice contains the feature to save documents in a flat XML
>   format instead: If  a document is saved als .fodt file it keeps the
>   same data the .odt file would contain. Only that this time the data is
>   represented as human-readable text (which makes the work much easier
>   for the version control system) and not compressed.